# Using Asyncio to create new Python Processes

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I'm setting up a function to asynchronously start a new process to run a very cpu heavy function. Most of the documentation don't cover this thoroughly, and what I've pieced together doesn't seem to asynchronously work.

I have a function `procManager` which takes in a function, the args to pass into the function, and an object name for basic logging.

```
async def procManager(f,a,o):
    print(f"{o} started at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    p = Process(target=f, args=(a,))
    p_parent = os.getppid()   # parent process
    p_curr = os.getpid()     # current process
    print("parent process:", p_parent)
    print("current process:", p_curr)
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print(f"{o} finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    print("=========")
```

I have this cpu heavy function that runs Louvain's community detection on a networkX graph that I pass into `def procManager` to spawn on a new process.

```
def community(cg):
    start = timer()
    partition = c.best_partition(cg) #default louvain community detection
    v = {} #create dict to group nodes by community
    for key, value in sorted(partition.items()):
        v.setdefault(value, []).append(key)
    stop = timer()
    print(stop-start)
```

The main function looks as such. I'm initializing 2 graphs A and B of 3000 and 1000 nodes respectively, with an average degree of 5. I'm using a Jupyter notebook to run this, so I  use `await main()` instead of `asyncio.run`.

```
A = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(3000,5)  
B = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(1000,5)  

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(
        procManager(community, A, "A"))

    task2 = asyncio.create_task(
        procManager(community, B, "B"))

    print("async start")

await main()
```

What I'm trying to do is to get A and B processed asynchronously (i.e. start at the same time) but on different processes. Current outputs look like this, where A and B are processed on new processes but are blocking. I'll need to compute for A and B communities in an async manner because they'll be triggered by a rabbitMQ stream and responses need to be non-blocking.

```
async done
A started at 06:03:48
parent process: 5783
current process: 12121
11.424800566000158
A finished at 06:03:59
=========
B started at 06:03:59
parent process: 5783
current process: 12121
0.037437027999885686
B finished at 06:03:59
=========
```

Hope you guys can help!

Comment: You might want to have a look at `p.join()`. It blocks until the given process has finished. I assume, that this would be the reason for your blocking behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the problem is the `join()` method. It blocks until the process has finished. Also, you wouldn't even need `asyncio` for that. Have a look at this quick example:

```py
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def procManager(f,a,o):
    print(f"{o} started at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    p = Process(target=f, args=(a,))
    p.start()
    # p.join()
    print(f"{o} finished at {time.strftime('%X')}") # This will occur immediately
    print("=========")

def community(cg):
    for i in range(10):
        print("%s - %s" %(cg, i))
        time.sleep(1)

procManager(community, "This is A", "A")
procManager(community, "This is B", "B")
```

This should give you an idea on how to solve your problem. I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @TvG, what if the `community()` function had some return value. How would I access that from `procManager()` without having to use `join()`?

Answer (score 0):

one of examoles for run asyncio in processpool:

```
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
        result = await loop.run_in_executor(
            pool, cpu_bound_function, args)
        print('custom process pool', result)
```

run_in_exacutor() works fine howewer it's not best way to use asyncio

Answer (score -2):

In regards to Asyncio, you need to use the `asyncio.create_task` method. The trick to this method is that you should only specify the funcitons that you have declared async. In order to run them, you should use `await asyncio.gather`.

Example would be:

```py
import asyncio

async def print_hello(name):
    print("Hello! {}".format(name))

name_list = ["billy", "bob", "buffalo bob"]

for item in name_list:
    await asyncio.gather(print_hello(item))
```

The most simple form of creating and running subprocesses with asyncio is the create_task method as outlined here: [Asyncio Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks)

Hope this helps!

Comment: The title says creating new processes with asyncio, using multiprocessing and asyncio over complicates things when asyincio has its own built in method of handling multiple processes, which is why I commented my comment.

Comment: A downvote is feedback meaning that "the answer is not useful (according to the voter)". In this case it's due to your answer not covering the OP's problem (`p.join()` being blocking), nor explaining how to use asyncio to create new processes. Note that `create_task` has nothing to do with processes, it just runs a coroutine, whereas the OP is talking about actual OS-level processes.

Comment: Although the blocking aspect is what he is looking for. Asyncio is the replacement for multithreading in python versions 3.x and up. I have created a project based on asyncio, and it handles both blocking and multiple processes(at OS level) with no issues. 

What I am saying, is there is no reason to downvote, or condescend, if the method suggested is more efficient than the original way of attempting. Clearly the OP is having issues with mixing the 2 libraries.

Comment: Asyncio is not a "replacement for multithreading", and even less for multiprocessing, they serve different purposes. The OP is indeed having issues with mixing asyncio and multiprocessing, but your answer doesn't help with those issues at all, nor does it clarify them.

Comment: [Asyncio Concurrency and multi threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#concurrency-and-multithreading)